# Texture bake in cycles

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, texture-baking

Is it possible to bake texture without any lights and shadows but i dont want to lose quality of it. I want it to look like unlit texture.

When i bake my final work i get this: [image]

But i want it to look like this: [image]
Is it possible not to lose anything from your node editor but to be baked as i asked?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried *Bake Type* set to diffuse and *Influence* with only color enabled?

Comment: You can do the same for *Subsurface* and *Glossy*, but not all in one bake. The combined bake will need lighting.